# How do I know if I've bountied a question before?

Tags: support, bounty

Every so often, I go through my questions (on this site and on MSE) and find some old unanswered question that I still care about, and put a bounty on it. However, my memory is far from perfect, so I would like to know:

> Is there a way to find out whether I've already bountied a question in the past?

Ideally, I'd like to see a list of all questions I've bountied. I know that this information can be gotten by reading through my reputation history, but this quickly becomes impractical if the question in question (heh) was bountied more than a year ago (as is quite possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see list of all your past bounties in your profile page on [the bounty tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=bounties). (You can choose between viewing active, offered and earned bounties there.) It works exactly the same [on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bounties).

If you want to see past bounties for a particular question (be it yours or by other users), you can look at the revision history or the timeline. As an example, here is [revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/252406/revisions) and [timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/252406/timeline) of one specific post.